# Using generics from non-generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a problem with generics. I have written a generic class. I derive other classes from this class.

Finally I would like to use this derived class in another class but I haven't found working solution how to get it working.

Here is my simplified example:

```
// Generic base class
public class Information<T>
{
    public T StatusCode;
    public bool Changed;
}

public class Status1 : Information<Status1.Codes>
{
    public enum Codes { None = 0, }
    public string AdditionalStatusInformation;

    public Status1()
    {
         StatusCode = Codes.None;
    }
}

public class Status2 : Information<Status2.Codes>
{
    public enum Codes { OK = 0, }

    public Status2()
    {
         StatusCode = Codes.OK;
    }
}
```

Everything good so far. I am sending and reading this information using Json and this approach works for both receiver and transmitter. Works fine with Status1 and Status2 classes.

Finally I have generic ErrorReporter class where I would like to use my Status1 or Status2 class. Seems this is not possible.

```
public class ErrorReporter<T> where T : Information<T>
{
    public readonly T Info = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Info.Changed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Info.StatusCode.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Info));
        }
    }
}
```

Seems there is no way to instantiate this class properly.

I tried these

```
new ErrorReporter<Status1>()
new ErrorReporter<Status1.Codes>()
new ErrorReporter<Information<Status1.Codes>()
```

I am getting

```
The type 'TestApp.Program.Status1' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in
the generic type or method 'TestApp.Program.ErrorReporter<T>'.
There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TestApp.Program.Status1' to
'TestApp.Program.Information<TestApp.Program.Status1>'.
```

or similar error message.

I probably should move my ErrorReporter class to Information class.

But what is correct way to instantiate new object from my ErrorReporter class? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You require `T` to derive from `Information<T>`, which isn't what you want.

I guess you need this, where you need to supply the type argument for the generic:

```
public class ErrorReporter<T, S> where T : Information<S>
{ }
```

With a little extra, you can remove the reflection call:

```
public class ErrorReporter<T, S> where T : Information<S>, new()
{
    public readonly T Info = new T();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to use `T` for two purposes:

- The source of the status code (you're calling `StatusCode` on it)
- The type of the status code (it's the type argument for `Information<T>`)

Now you *could* just make `ErrorReporter` generic in two type parameters instead:

```
public class ErrorReporter<TSource, TCode> where TSource : Information<TCode>
{
    public readonly TSource Info = Activator.CreateInstance<TSource>();

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Info.Changed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Info.StatusCode.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Info));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could use:

```
new ErrorReporter<Status1, Status1.Codes>()
```

Or you could make it generic in just the code type, but avoid constructing the source by reflection:

```
public class ErrorReporter<T>
{
    // You could expose this as a property if you want. I would
    // advise against exposing it as a field
    private readonly Information<T> source;

    public ErrorReporter(Information<T> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Info.Changed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(source.StatusCode.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source));
        }
    }
}
```

And construct it as:

```
var reporter = new ErrorReporter<Status1.Codes>(new Status1());
```